# windows 7 enterprise : 'net use' fails with 'system error 50 has occurred'

Tags: windows, networking, hard-drive, cmd.exe

Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 x64

I was having problems mapping a local drive to a network shared folder, so I opened cmd.exe and ran :

```
> net use
> System error 50 has occurred
> The request is not supported.
```

I've Google'd this extensively and apparently a lot of people have this problem, but very few have found solutions.

I investigated some of root causes others uncovered , such as mangled registry key values at :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\HwOrder
```

How can I further diagnose this issue ?

What could have caused a very basic system-level command such as `net use` to begin failing ?

but in those respects my system seems to be fine

Comment: Is the network shared folder a Samba or a Windows share ? Also, is your machine a member of a domain ?

Comment: I've looked around the net a bit, and it looks like part of your networking stack is corrupted.  Time to reimage/reinstall/reformat.

Comment: The network shared folder I was attempting to connect to is Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.  But my understanding of `net use` is that it should list all shares. In the case when there are no shares, it should display a message `no entries in the list`.

Comment: @BaltoStar  That's correct.  `net use` by itself should return a "table" listing the mapped drives, or [something like the image here](http://www.cezeo.com/tips-and-tricks/net-use-command/), if there are none.  Like I said, it's time for you to reimage/reinstall/reformat.

Answer (score 5):

Start `regedit.exe`, and change the `ProviderOrder` value in the following registry keys

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\HwOrder
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\Order
```

from `,,RDPNP,LanmanWorkstation,webclient` to `RDPNP,LanmanWorkstation,webclient`.

Source: [To map Network Disk in Windows 7 error — SOLVED](http://pocketsun.net/windows/to-map-network-disk-in-windows-7-error-solved/)

Comment: For me, this issue showed up after installing SSHFS, and the keys looked like: "RDPNP,LanmanWorkstation,webclient,Dokan". I removed the ",Dokan", and it worked. But, I assume, SSHFS is borked now.

Comment: This fixed my problem with win_sshfs as well.  I ended up uninstalling it and still had to fix the registry key.  It just wasn't worth the freezing when accessing disks.

Comment: @Codex24  this regarding the dokan used by win-sshfs was quite the catch. but I still need to use win-sshfs. bummer

Comment: Thanks, this fixed me problem as well. I had a `Dokan` entry in each key, and removing it from `HwOrder` fixed it, too. (`Dokan` was installed through some NFS client, I believe.)